# How can i get the content of a specific div sharing the same class with other div ? i get an empty string with 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, this

What i tried :

```
const adressLine = $('.adressLine');
    adressLine.on('click',()=>{
        console.log('button cliked');
        var text = adressLine.text();
        console.log(text);
    });
```

console result, i get all of the strings, not what i want  :

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwuI4.png)

so i find a solution in other discussions:

```
const adressLine = $('.adressLine');
    adressLine.on('click',()=>{
        console.log('button cliked');
        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log(text);
    });
```

it returned me an empty string , why ?

[Second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neXHD.png)

Comment: Add the relevant HTML part as well to the question.

Comment: `$(this).text()` should return the text of the button that was clicked.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Is it a `<button>` or `<input type="button">`? There's no `.text()` for `<input>`, the button displays its value, so use `.val()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Try with

```
const adressLine = $('.adressLine');
adressLine.on('click',function(){
    console.log('button cliked');
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```